# Must I have a common DB for all users active sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

Here I come again ;)

I am doing an application where each user will have their own DB.
Is it ok if I store session for each user in their individual DB? Or is it for some reason convenient to have active sessions in a common DB for all users?

Sorry about my question, I am kind of new to this level. :) I am working with PHP and MySQL, if that makes any difference, although I thik the question is language independent.

Comment: The real question is, why would each user have a separate DB.

Comment: ^yup that would be very unusual.

Comment: You *are* new at this. Each a DB, or did you mean "table"? Unless you're wanting to start your own hosting company/service.

Comment: For starters I thought it would be faster. Say user 1 logs in, I connect to his or her DB, and perform the queries there instead of in a huge amount of rows. And then I also thought it would be better structured; say he has friends (it's just an example), he could have a friends table, with a column with his friends ids, stuff like that. Is it that wrong?

Comment: `huge amount of rows`.... how many rows are you talking about? millions? billions? And even then, a well indexed database doesn't have any problems with tables of that size

Comment: @Mark ok, and I don't know how many there will be. I still don't understand why it is a bad approach, even if it is not common. I guess I will use one DB then but I would really like to understand why

Comment: It's a bad approach because you then have to maintain hundreds(?) of databases, you might have hundreds(?) of databases being accessed at any time (which will kill your database server). And you're creating a ton of work for yourself, and losing control of your users in the process

Comment: It won't be faster (in almost all cases), databases are specifically designed to handle precisely such cases. It's a bad idea because you lose all ability to query related data, for instance, how would you implement 'these two users have these friends in common'? You'd have to write it into your app. In one db, the db does it for you, you just have to query. DB-per-user essentially removes almost all advantages to using a db in the first place.

Comment: Thanks pvg, and thank you everyone. I marked this as solved

Comment: Imagine the administrative hassle it'll be to maintain a database of this design. Multiple dbs with multiple tables with multiple rows to serve a single purpose which can be done inside multiple tables of a single schema (db)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical application, there will only be **one** database with **several** tables, where each table can have **several** records.

**Sessions**
You can just save sessions the same way you would add a record to database.

**Profile Details / Friendship** 
This is where **relationships** take place.
Consider the image below. Credits to the owner on w3stack(dot)org.

[image]

Focus and try to study on the three tables above: `Users`, `Friendships`, `Friends(virtual table)`. Ignore the `virtual table` concept for now, so you will not be much confused.

It is really a **BAD**, and I mean **BAD** approach to create individual databases for each users. What if you thought of adding a "following" and "follower" feature to your application? You would need to add another table, and re-add all those friends from another db. If **UserA** will have 100 friends with each database, you wouldn't want to query all those 100 databases.

To end, just use a single DB, and identify relationships according to your application features. It is important to plan your structure before you actually apply it on hands-on. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am glad I asked here :), I was gonna make a mess

Comment: Well, that's normal for someone who still starting in PHP and MySQL. I was not exempted of that scenario when I was still working my way up. :)